# double loop python with matrix

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I have a situation with a double loop in python3.6.

I have a matrix with string values, all the position in the matrix are not full. So I have many position with juste '' char. I want to take the first value of each line in the matrix. To do that I've tried a double comprehension list like this :

```
matrix = data[1:,6:68]
price = [[int(matrix[i,j]) if j!='' for j in matrix[i][j] ] for i in matrix[i]]
```

But when I run it, I receive this error :

```
price = [[int(matrix[i,j]) if j!='' for j in matrix[i][j] ] for i in matrix[i]]
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Could you help me please ?

C.

Comment: can you provide a sample data of 'data' ?

Comment: to your error.......price = [[int(matrix[i,j]) for j in matrix[i][j] if j!='' ] for i in matrix[i]]..........

Comment: Here, for i in matrix[i ] gives a list and when you use it as matrix[i][j] will throw error!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here
     `[[int(matrix[i,j]) if j!='' for j in matrix[i][j] ] for i in matrix[i]]`
is, `int(matrix[i,j]) if j!=''` and then followed by
 `matrix[i,j]` where, the variable i is a list as a result of first list comprehension and hence will throw the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Therefore,

```
 [i for i in matrix] #gives each row of matrix!
[[j for j in i if j!=''][0] for i in matrix] #gives all elements in each row that is not null.
```

so,

```
[[j for j in i if j!=''][0] for i in matrix] #first element of each row that isn't null!
```

Sample IO:

```
>>> matrix
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [[j for j in i if j!=''][0] for i in matrix]
[1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: If you feel that the answer is appropriate to your question, kindly accept it as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank's sorry the time delay :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a comprehension the condition comes after the iterator. i.e.

```
matrix = data[1:,6:68]
price = [[int(matrix[i,j]) for j in matrix[i][j] if j!='' ] for i in matrix[i]]
```

Comment: Here, for i in matrix[i ] gives a list and when you use it as matrix[i][j] will throw error!!